# English spelling and grammar exercise database

Tags: learning, software

I have a little odd question, probably borderline applicable to stackoverflow...

What I am looking to do is to write a Windows program, which I will give my kids to exercise in English spelling as well as grammar. I want it to be in a quiz-like format (like: If we *** [to cycle] to Dresden, it will be a fantastic trip). However if there are too few different sentences in a quiz, kids would just remember those, and they will be filling them mechanically instead of learning, so I need to get an access to a big pool of exercises, and those should be in a program-accessible format - xml, or database, or some text with a clear format.

Is anyone aware of any English exercise database available in such form?

Comment: I don't know of a well-organized exercise database. It shouldn't be too hard to find a corpus with sentences and make your own, though. If you have a subscription (or belong to a library with one) the [OEC example sentences](http://oxforddictionaries.com/words/example-sentences) might be a good place to start.

Answer (score 2):

There are many dictionary sites like Dictionary.com that provide API access to their data. Dictionary.com offers an [example sentences](http://developer.dictionary.com/products/examples) call that can be queried with a random value to return a random sample sentence in XML.  I would give that a try.